# Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE) : Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl. How to fix this?

Tags: r

I am trying to get data from twitter, I have the authentication as well. During the handshake command i get the following error

Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :    Protocol  https not supported or disabled in libcurl. How to fix this?

Comment: What OS? What R version? What are the exact commands you are running>?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same error and it was because I had a space in the start of the URL.
Worked well after removing the space.